# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel при запросе к redmine

Tags: c#, redmine

Приветствую. 
Есть приложение для сбора статистики по багрепортам jira+redmine. Есть класс отвечающий за redmine:

```
static string host = "redmine.ru";
static string apiKey = Login.decryptPassword(Settings.Default.skynetApiKey);
static RedmineManager manager = new RedmineManager(host, apiKey);
static List<RedmineProject> redmineProject = new List<RedmineProject>();
static List<RedmineUserStats> redmineIssue = new List<RedmineUserStats>();
static double blocker;
static double critical;
static double major;
static double minor;
static double trivial;
//Get issues.
public static void getSkynetIssues(string author)
{
    var parameters = new NameValueCollection
    {
        {RedmineKeys.STATUS_ID, "*"},
        {RedmineKeys.CREATED_ON, "><"+MainForm.dateStart+"|"+MainForm.dateEnd+""},
    };
    var issues = manager.GetObjects<Issue>(parameters);
    foreach (var issue in issues)
    {
        redmineIssue.Add(new RedmineUserStats()
        {
            Priority = issue.Priority.Name,
            Author = issue.Author.Name
        });
    }
    foreach (var user in UserDataFiller.usersData)
    {
        calculateIssues(user.Name);
    }
    }
public static void calculateIssues()
{
    foreach (var issue in redmineIssue)
    {
        if (issue.Priority.Contains("Immediate") && issue.Author.Equals(author)) { blocker++; }
        else if (issue.Priority.Contains("Urgent") && issue.Author.Equals(author)) { critical++; }
        else if (issue.Priority.Contains("High") && issue.Author.Equals(author)) { critical++; } 
        else if (issue.Priority.Contains("Normal") && issue.Author.Equals(author)) { major++; }
        else if (issue.Priority.Contains("Low") && issue.Author.Equals(author)) { trivial++; }
    }
    IssuesFiller.fillIssuesData(author,  blocker,  critical,  major,  minor,  trivial);
    blocker = critical = major = minor = trivial = 0;
}
```

Месяц назад все работало, но сейчас при запросе к redmine вылезает эксепшен:

```
Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineException: Запрос был прерван: Не удалось создать защищенный канал SSL/TLS.
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
   в System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
   в Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineManager.ExecuteDownload[T](String address, String methodName, NameValueCollection parameters)
   --- end of inner exception stack trace ---
   в Redmine.Net.Api.Extensions.WebExtensions.HandleWebException(WebException exception, String method, MimeFormat mimeFormat)
   в Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineManager.ExecuteDownloadList[T](String address, String methodName, NameValueCollection parameters)
   в Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineManager.GetPaginatedObjects[T](NameValueCollection parameters)
   в Redmine.Net.Api.RedmineManager.GetObjects[T](NameValueCollection parameters)
   в KPI_Calc.Skynet.getSkynetIssues(String author) в D:\Work\repositories\KPI Calc\KPI Calc\Main\Trackers\Skynet.cs:строка 53
   в KPI_Calc.MainForm.getSkynetIssues() в D:\Work\repositories\KPI Calc\KPI Calc\Forms\MainForm.cs:строка 101
   в KPI_Calc.MainForm.<>c__DisplayClass21_0.<worker>b__0(Object o, DoWorkEventArgs args) в D:\Work\repositories\KPI Calc\KPI Calc\Forms\MainForm.cs:строка 124
   в System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
   в System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
```

В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-умолчанию библиотека подключается используя ssl 3 протокол. Для корректной  работы необходимо было использовать при подключении Tls 1.2 протокол.

```
static RedmineManager manager = new RedmineManager(host, apiKey, MimeFormat.Xml, true, null, SecurityProtocolType.Tls12);
```